# Modifying a list of structs in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto, changeset

I have a blog with a backend showing a list of Posts.  Each Post has a `publish_on` value which is a datetime -- if the current time is later than `publish_on`, the Post is active (Post has a boolean virtual field called `active`).

When I query the Repo for a list of Posts, I'd like to go through the list, and set Post's `active` to true if the current time is after `publish_on`.

What is the most "Elixirian" way to do this?  (Also, what is the Elixir community's version of "Pythonic"?)

## models/post.ex

```
defmodule MyApp.Post do
  use MyApp.Web, :model

  schema "posts" do
    field :title, :string
    field :content, :text
    field :publish_on, Ecto.DateTime
    field :active, :boolean, virtual: true, default: false

    timestamps()
  end
```

## controllers/post_controller.ex

```
MyApp.PostController
  def index(conn, _params) do
    query = from p in Post,
    posts = Repo.all(query)

    ###I assume some kind of mapping goes here

    render(conn, "index.html", posts: posts)
  end
```

## templates/post/index.html.eex

```
<table class="table">
<%= for post <- @posts do %>
    <%= if post.active do %>
      <tr class="published">
    <% else %>
      <tr class="unpublished">
    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go through the posts using `for`, compare `DateTime.utc_now` with `post.publish_on` using `DateTime.compare`, and if it's `:gt`, set `active` to `true`:

```
posts = Repo.all(query)

now = DateTime.utc_now

posts = for post <- posts do
  case DateTime.compare(now, post.publish_on) do
    :gt -> %{post | active: true}
    _ -> post
  end
end
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for.  I seem to be getting this error for `DateTime.compare()`:  `no function clause matching in DateTime.compare/2`.  It doesn't throw this if I run `DateTime.compare(now, now)`, so I'm guessing it has to do with post.publish_on's type.

Comment: @MarkKaravan looks like it's `Ecto.DateTime`. Until you upgrade to a version that uses the new `DateTime`, you can use `DateTime.utc_now` -> `Ecto.DateTime.utc` and `DateTime.compare` -> `Ecto.DateTime.compare`.

Answer (score 2):

You can initialize the virtual field in your query:

```
query = from p in Post, select: %{p | active: (s.publish_on < ^DateTime.utc_now())}
posts = Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: Very useful.  What is the name of the %{this | that} structure?

Comment: @MarkKaravan http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/structs.html#accessing-and-updating-structs just refers to it as the 'update syntax'.